# watch persistentVolumes with a kubernetes go-client

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

In this code I am watching the services, and it is working, my question is, how could I do to watch events when a `persistentVolume` is being created? I have checked [the source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/7b18d6600f6b0022e31c46b46875beffd85cc71a/kubernetes/typed/core/v1/persistentvolume.go#L93) and it seems to return an interface, but I am not really familiar of how to make it work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

     "github.com/golang/glog"

     "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
     "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/fields"
     "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
     "k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache"
     "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func main() {
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "")
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorln(err)
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        glog.Errorln(err)
    }

    watchlist := cache.NewListWatchFromClient(
        clientset.CoreV1().RESTClient(),
        string(v1.ResourceServices),
        v1.NamespaceAll,
        fields.Everything(),
    )
    _, controller := cache.NewInformer( // also take a look at NewSharedIndexInformer
        watchlist,
        &v1.Service{},
        0, //Duration is int64
        cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
            AddFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
                fmt.Printf("service added: %s \n", obj)
            },
            DeleteFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
                fmt.Printf("service deleted: %s \n", obj)
            },
            UpdateFunc: func(oldObj, newObj interface{}) {
                fmt.Printf("service changed \n")
            },
         },
     )
         // I found it in k8s scheduler module. Maybe it's help if you 
    interested in.
     // serviceInformer := 
    cache.NewSharedIndexInformer(watchlist, 
     &v1.Service{}, 0, cache.Indexers{
     //     cache.NamespaceIndex: cache.MetaNamespaceIndexFunc,
     // })
     // go serviceInformer.Run(stop)
    stop := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(stop)
    go controller.Run(stop)
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Similar of what they are doing [here with pods](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/ee7a1ba5cdf1292b67a1fdf1fa28f90d2a7b0084/examples/workqueue/main.go#L165).

Comment: Can you specify what are you having trouble with exactly? Why creating a list watch for a resource `"persistentvolumes"` similarly to the example you've posted doesn't work? Also, have tried this way: https://medium.com/programming-kubernetes/building-stuff-with-the-kubernetes-api-part-4-using-go-b1d0e3c1c899 ?

Comment: changing `&v1.Service{}` to `&v1.PersistentVolume{}` throughout would make it work.